# How can I fetch the SMTP headers after sending email?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

I'm able to send emails using `smtplib` with ease. What I'm struggling with is reading the actual headers that were sent one. Specifically, I'm looking to read the `Message-ID` and `References`.

I thought at first that `sendmail()` would return them, but it does not.

Found that I'm able to redirect `smtpilb.stderr` to my own function and parse out the data that I need. Is there a better way that would allow me to do say:

```
headers['References']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `sendmail()` I am not sure how to access the headers, because you don't have a `Message` object in that case. However, if you use `send_message` instead - which is very similar to `sendmail()` - and pass it an `email.message.Message` object, then all of the email message headers and their values are stored in a dict in your `Message` object. So e.g.,  Message-ID can be accessed from an email message object `msg` with `msg['Message-ID']`, subject can be accessed using `msg['Subject']`, etc. I don't think anything will be stored in `message-id` unless you put it there yourself though. You can 'roll your own' Message-ID using `make_msgid()` from `email.utils`:

```
from email.utils import make_msgid

msg['Message-ID'] = make_msgid()
```